# To spellcheck my code in Vim for English/German/Finnish

Tags: vim, spell-check

**How can you spellcheck your LaTeX document for English/German/Finnish?**

I would like to check my spelling for one of my white papers.
Its comments are written in German, TODO -comments in Finnish and codes in English.

I know how you can spellcheck English but not the other two languages.

I am using at the moment the method of moving my documents to OpenOffice and then spell checking there. However, this is very ineffective.

I would like to

1. find parts of code in different languages
2. put these parts to separate files such that I can spellcheck them
3. and then combine the spellchecked files back to one

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you can setup multiple spelling files in **`VIM`** to work together.

```
set spelllang=en,de
```

- Read up the [VIM pages](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html) for configurations (and, if required, creation of new spelling files)
- You may need to fetch some of the `.spl` spelling files if they are not available in your `spell/` directory
- Check specifically, `spl` files, `sug` files, [`spellang`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27spelllang%27), [`spellsuggest`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27spellsuggest%27)

You can also check [**Vimchant : Fast on-the-fly spell-checker based on Enchant**](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2345)

---

[**Using latexmk, vim spell checking and vim latex-suite**](http://www.tjansson.dk/?p=278)
(it also refers to Sourceforge [**Kile**](http://kile.sourceforge.net/), an Integrated LaTeX Environment)

Comment: But where do I get the `spl` files from? on http://ftp.vim.org/vim/runtime/spell/de/ I can only find `diff` files.

Answer (score 1):

You [use](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=465) [`aspell`](http://aspell.net). Granted there's a built in checked in vim 7, but I don't know if it supports TeX. I do know that `aspell` does.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I am using in my Makefile to invoke [hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) (notice the -t parameter for LaTeX compatibility):

```
spell-check: $(FILE).tex
    hunspell -d en_GB -t $<
```

You have to check the available dictionaries on your system (on my Ubuntu I used '`locate .dic`'). And I suppose you can create a macro in vim to call this specific command.

Edit:

Hunspell has its own dictionaries (see the [list of hunspell dictionaries](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries)), and you can use myspell dictionaries as well, as hunspell is based on myspell

Comment: I found dictionaries for German and English. However, I cannot find the dictionary for Finnish. For instance, no dictionary for Finnish at http://ftp.vim.org/vim/runtime/spell/